# Transverse wave on a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

A transverse wave on a string is described by the following wave function.
$y = 0.110 \sin(\frac{\pi}{12}x + 3\pi t)$

where $x$ and $y$ are in meters and $t$ is in seconds.
(a) Determine the transverse speed at $t = 0.240~\rm s$ for an element of the string located at $x = 1.20~\rm m$.

I dont understand what they mean by the term speed. I used the equation $V=AW\cos(kx-\omega t)$ but still it says I have the wrong answer. And yes my calculator is in radians.

Comment: You have a misconception between the speed of the wave and the speed of the y variable around a point. Also what is "A"?

Comment: @Mauricio what is the y variable? and A is the amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different speeds in this scenario. There is the longitudinal speed (aka wave speed or *phase speed*) of any fixed value of y of the wave as it moves along the string. This is speed in the x direction. And there is the transverse speed of any point on the string with a fixed value of x. This is speed in the y direction.

The question is asking for the speed in the y direction, so you find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ while holding x constant.

To find the wave speed you find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ while holding y constant, which means that the phase $kx-\omega t$ is held constant.